# Removing row from Razor for loop generated table causes mass data loss on save

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am providing users with a mass edit/add/delete interface.  You can see the skeleton from my earlier question: 
[Add new row for new record to the end of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889033/add-new-row-for-new-record-to-the-end-of-table).

I've added a jQuery row delete button that removes a row from the html table.  When I post my data back to the server it looks like this:

```
Config[0].ConfigurationId:222
Config[0].Parent:abc
Config[1].ConfigurationId:333
Config[1].Parent:abc2
Config[3].ConfigurationId:444
Config[3].Parent:abc3
... more data like this
```

In this case I've deleted the item at index 2.  When the Model Binder binds the model anything after index 1 gets ignored causing the logic in my action to delete all of those rows since they were not returned, and thus presumably were meant to be deleted.

I could use javascript to rename all of the controls so that they are numbered correctly, but it seems like there should be an easier fix...

Comment: What is `Config`?  A `List<T>` I presume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's how the [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) works with collections.

From the [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) article:

> The index must be an unbroken sequence of integers starting at 0 and increasing by 1 for each element

To make the model binder work with the non-sequential indices, you have to add a hidden input with the `*.Index` name for each item. In your case that might be:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Config.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Config[i].ConfigurationId)
        <input type="hidden" name="Config.Index" value="@i" />
        @Html.EditorFor(m=>Model.Config[i].RowNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=>Model.Config[i].Parent)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I would suggest you to read this article for more information, it's great.

Comment: Beat me to it.  This is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Zabavsky's answer will definitely work. Another option is to just hide the row that's been deleted, and flag a property on it to indicate it's been deleted. I'm not sure how you're handling deletes once the data is posted back, but this might be easier.

Comment: A valid option, but I'm going to go with Zabavsky's answer since it requires no change to my model.